# In stacking for machine learning which order should you train the models in?

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently learning to do stacking in a machine learning problem. I am going to get the outputs of the first model and use these outputs as features for the second model.

My question is: Does the order matter? I am using a lasso regression model and a boosted tree. In my problem the regression model outperforms the boosted tree. I am thinking therefore that I should use the regression tree second and the boosted tree first.

What are the factors I need to think about when making this decision?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try feature engineering to create more features?
Don't try to use predictions from one model as features for another model. 
You can try using K-means to cluster similar training samples.
For stacking, just use different models and then average the results (assuming that you have a continuous y variable).

Comment: Why can't you use predictions from one model as features for another. This is a valid technique.

Comment: Why not use a neural net then?

Comment: Yeah, could be an option but i don't think I have enough data.

Comment: I understand. Also, it's a valid technique but if you don't have the right predictions from the previous model, don't you think you might also add noise to the data? That would result in assumptions that do not exist. Anyway, you can try different techniques and let us know what worked best for you.